# How do I create a new project collection with the existing empty database using power shell script?

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have the sample script below to create a project collection (which is working fine):

```
# Load client OM assembly.
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TestAgent\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll");
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TestAgent\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll");
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TestAgent\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.dll");
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TestAgent\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.dll");

$instanceBaseUrl = "http://TFSserver:8080/tfs/";
$tfsServer = new-object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConfigurationServer $instanceBaseUrl;

$tpcSvc = $tfsServer.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.ITeamProjectCollectionService]);
$job = $tpcSvc.QueueCreateCollection(
    "SampleMyCollectionNameTest_1215",      # collection name.
    "",                  # description.
    $false,              # don't make this the default collection.
    "~/SampleMyCollectionNameTest_1215/",   # virtual directory.
    "Started",           # State after creation.
    $null,               # no tokens.
    "Server=SLQ\Instance;Integrated Security=SSPI;",       # The SQL instance to create the collection on. Specify SERVER\INSTANCE if not using default instance
    $null,               # null because the collection database doesn't already exist.
    $null)               # null because the collection database doesn't already exist.

$collection = $tpcSvc.WaitForCollectionServicingToComplete($job)
```

How do I create a new project collection with the existing empty database by using power shell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the script to create a team project collection on remote by using existing empty database

```
# Load client OM assembly.
[Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a");

$instanceBaseUrl = "http://<tfsservername>:8080/tfs/";
$tfsServer = new-object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConfigurationServer $instanceBaseUrl;

$collectionName = "<CollectionName>"
$sqlConnectionString = "Server=<SQLservername>;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

$servicingTokens = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[String,String]'
$servicingTokens.Add("SharePointAction","None")
$servicingTokens.Add("ReportingAction","None")

$databaseCategoryConnectionStrings = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[String,String]'
$databaseCategoryConnectionStrings.Add('Framework','Data Source=SQLservername;Initial Catalog=<Existing Empty Database Name>;Integrated Security=True;')

$defaultConnectionString = "Data Source=SQLservername;Initial Catalog=<Existing Empty Database Name>;Integrated Security=True;"

$tpcSvc = $tfsServer.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.ITeamProjectCollectionService]);
$job = $tpcSvc.QueueCreateCollection(
    $collectionName,      # collection name.
    "",                  # description.
    $false,              # don't make this the default collection.
    "~/$collectionName/",   # virtual directory.
    "Started",           # State after creation.
    $servicingTokens,               # no SP, no reporting.
    $sqlConnectionString,       # The SQL instance to create the collection on. Specify SERVER\INSTANCE if not using default instance
    $defaultConnectionString,   # defaultConnectionString.
        $databaseCategoryConnectionStrings)               # databaseCategoryConnectionStrings

$collection = $tpcSvc.WaitForCollectionServicingToComplete($job)
```